# How to listen App launch and close in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to track some logs event(**only once**) when App launch and close.

First I do this in `Home` screen `componentDiMount()`, but it will be instantiated several times in some case, causing repetitive launch event log.

=============== Edit =================

`AppState` can only listen **background** and **active** event.

When closing app on Android (press back key or close in recents app menu), it actually back to **background**. It takes the app back to **active** from **background** when reopen the app. Which is the same as toggle app between **background** and **active**(not close)

So I can't determine whether it is **first launch** or **toggling app status**  using `AppState`

Comment: You can try `AppState` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html

Comment: @junlin did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

### On App Launch

In general, `useEffect` with an empty dependency array is what you're looking for.

In React Native, code can be running when app state is not active, but `useEffect` with an empty dependency array will be running on first app launch.

If you're using dependency values, you can use `useRef` to track if it's handled in first app launch.

```
const onLaunchRef = React.useRef<boolean>();

useEffect(() => {
  if (onLaunchRef.current) {
    return;
  }
  doSomething(state1, state2);
  onLaunchRef.current = true;
}, [state1, state2]);
```

You can combine this with [useAppState](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#useappstate):

```
import { useAppState } from '@react-native-community/hooks'

const onLaunchRef = React.useRef<boolean>();
const appState = useAppState();

useEffect(() => {
  if (onLaunchRef.current) {
    return;
  }
  if (appState !== 'active') {
    return;
  }
  doSomething(state1, state2);
  onLaunchRef.current = true;
}, [state1, state2, appState]);
```

### On App Close

You can use the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    doSomething(state1, state2);
  };
}, [state1, state2]);
```

Or use `useAppState`:

```
const appState = useAppState();
useEffect(() => {
  if (appState !== 'active') {
    doSomething();
  }
}, [appState]);
```

However, actual close event does not exist in React Native. This is somewhat tricky problem to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Following answer was written when OP didn't edit the question to add info about the limitations of AppState.

Using `AppState`.

From [Official Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate#docsNav):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native'

class AppStateExample extends Component {

  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
    );
  }

}
```